# Move inside next quotes?

Tags: cursor-movement

I have a file with several lines like so:

```
{"latin": "", "french": "", "italian": "", "catalan": "", "portuguese": "", "romanian": "", "spanish": "", "english": ""}
```

I want to quickly move between the empty quotes to enter data. Is there a short-cut that could be used here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`f"` jumps to the next quote, and `F"` jumps to the previous one. `3f"` jumps three more quotes, and so on. This seems enough to me. If the cursor is inside the quote, and you want to jump to the position just before the ending quote, `t"` may be used, and similar is said of `T"`. In your case, `e` (jump to the last character of the current word) and `b` (jump to the first character of the current word) also do the same thing.

Comment: Note that `;` in normal mode repeats the last `fFtT` command, allowing for even faster movement.

Comment: On a similar note `,` repeats the last search as well, but searches backwards on the line.

Comment: Also, both `;` and `,` are commonly remapped (to `:` and mapleader respectively), so if anyone is using a vimrc copied from the internet the default behaviour may not work.

Answer (score 3):

- Search for empty quotes: `/""`;
- Repeat search with <kbd>n</kbd> key;
- Enter text into empty quotes with <kbd>a</kbd> key.